# (ObjectDisposedException) cannot upload FormFile to disk space

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to unit-test method

[Here I instantiate new FormFile from disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktjip.png)

Here I use static method,with file and path to folder

```
var id= await ContentSaver.Save(file, path + "\\");
```

[Than I try to save that file back to disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhWjP.png)

And VS throw an exception "System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a closed file."
How to solve it?

[This is stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqPZb.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code/errors/stack traces. They cannot be searched nor copy/pasted. The links may rot over time potentially rendering your question meaningless in the future. All questions on stack overflow should be self contained. Further, it's orders of magnitude easier for you as the asker to copy/paste your code directly, then surely it is to take screenshots, upload and then link to them. Finally it displays a level of disrespect towards the people you expect to solve **your** problem on their own time, by essentially requiring them to do extra work to obtain all the facts.

Comment: Well, I'll keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer at your first code part (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktjip.png). You create the stream in using scope and dispose it at once. To avoid it copy the content of your file into MemoryStream (do not need to be deposed) and set as source of FormFile

```
        IFormFile formFile;
        using (var fstream = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var mstream = new MemoryStream();
            fstream.CopyTo(mstream);
            formFile = new FormFile(mstream, 0, mstream.Length, null, mstream.Name);
        }
        // here fstream is disposed, but not mstream, and you can use your FormFile instance
        // MemoryStream does not need to be disposed explicitly, it do not posess any OS specific handlers, GC is enought.
```

Comment: Could u show me a little example?